# Show a loading img while inserting into database from code behind

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net, vb.net

I have an sql insert that's activated on a asp button click.

```
Try
    SqlDataSource_CreateFormulation.Insert()
    GvMultiBatchJobActivity.DataBind()
Catch ex As Exception
```

This insert can take 2-3 minutes. Once you click the button to create a formulation, there is no indication on the webpage that it's inserting the data. Then 2-3 minutes later it finishes the insert and updates a GridView and then an Update Panel.

What's an easy way I can indicate to the user that it's inserting data?

I've tried calling a modal before the insert and closing it after, it doesn't work because the page never gets a chance to open/close the modals. I've tried using Update Panel Progress but that doesn't work because it's not stalling on update.

Any tips?

Comment: How is this server-side code being initiated on the web page?

Comment: Have a loading gif in a hidden element, then show it when you click the button using JavaScript.

Comment: @ScottMarcus What do you mean by being initiated? It's just an asp:button that's within an updatepanel on the front end. When clicked it calls a code behind function that does the sql insert. It hangs on the insert for 3 minutes then it databinds and updates the panel.

Comment: @JackReilly Yes, that's what I meant. I think Seano666 has got your answer.